# How can I optimize my spark application to join two rdd having size greater than cluster memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to join two RDD each taking `10 GB of memory`. But the cluster memory I am having is just `15 GB`. Is it possible to optimize the code somehow so that we can join these RDD?

I thought of persisting the RDD in `DISK` but it seems to be not working.
IS there any optimization technique that we can use to encounter such problem?

Comment: Increase the shuffle partitions, and spark will do the splitting thing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a necessary condition that the cluster should have more memory than the dataset. However, that helps to increase the performance.

The persist to DISK_ONLY won't help if you have a single join. In case you are trying to multiple joins you would need to persist and count to force the DAG evaluation.

Anyway, the best way is to increase the Dataset partitions and shuflle partition (200 is default).

`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5000`

and then join.

Comment: This works.... Is there any other way where we can sort the rdd and then join.... Will it help? I am not sure.... I'm kinda new to spark so don't have enough idea.

Comment: Sorting won't help. Spark doesn't remember whether an rdd is sorted or not during join. There are other ways like bucketing the dataset which helps if the same  dataset is joined with various different datasets on the same key. However in your case since it is a single join i dont think that will help